# Remove double sender header

Tags: scrlttr2

`scrlttr2` shows the "header" containing sender details twice. Is it possible to show it once?

```
\documentclass[
  fontsize=11pt,
  paper=a4,
  parskip=half,
  enlargefirstpage=on,    % More space on first page
  fromalign=right,        % PLacement of name in letter head
  fromphone=on,           % Turn on phone number of sender
  fromrule=aftername,     % Rule after sender name in letter head
  addrfield=on,           % Adress field for envelope with window
  backaddress=on,         % Sender address in this window
  subject=beforeopening,  % Placement of subject
  locfield=narrow,        % Additional field for sender
  foldmarks=on,           % Print foldmarks
]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\setkomafont{fromname}{\sffamily \LARGE}
\setkomafont{fromaddress}{\sffamily}%% statt \small
\setkomafont{pagenumber}{\sffamily}
\setkomafont{subject}{\bfseries}
\setkomafont{backaddress}{\mdseries}

\LoadLetterOption{DIN}
\setkomavar{fromname}{Mario Rossi}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Via Roma 2,\\Frascati}
\setkomavar{fromphone}{+39 \,00\,00\,00\,000}
\setkomavar{fromemail}{goodboy@foo.com} % NON VIENE VISUALIZZATA
\setkomavar{backaddressseparator}{\enspace\textperiodcentered\enspace}
\setkomavar{signature}{(Mario Rossi)}
\setkomavar{place}{Frascati}
\setkomavar{date}{\today}
\setkomavar{enclseparator}{: }

\begin{document}
  \begin{letter}{To: Claire Laterfield}
    \setkomavar{subject}{Greetings}
    \opening{Dear Claire,}
    I am writing this letter because I have nothing better to do.

    \closing{Sincerely,}
  \end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there should be no `backaddress` change the value of this option to `off`:

```
`backaddress=off`
```

[image]

But then there is no need to change the font element `backaddress` or the variable `backaddressseparator`. Note that the letter-class option file `DIN` is loaded by the class as default.

```
\documentclass[
  fontsize=11pt,
  paper=a4,
  parskip=half,
  enlargefirstpage=on,    % More space on first page
  fromalign=right,        % PLacement of name in letter head
  fromphone=on,           % Turn on phone number of sender
  fromrule=aftername,     % Rule after sender name in letter head
  addrfield=on,           % Adress field for envelope with window
  % following line is changed:
  backaddress=off,         % Sender address in this window
  subject=beforeopening,  % Placement of subject
  locfield=narrow,        % Additional field for sender
  foldmarks=on,           % Print foldmarks
]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\setkomafont{fromname}{\sffamily \LARGE}
\setkomafont{fromaddress}{\sffamily}%% statt \small
\setkomafont{pagenumber}{\sffamily}
\setkomafont{subject}{\bfseries}
%\setkomafont{backaddress}{\mdseries}

%\LoadLetterOption{DIN}
\setkomavar{fromname}{Mario Rossi}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Via Roma 2,\\Frascati}
\setkomavar{fromphone}{+39 \,00\,00\,00\,000}
\setkomavar{fromemail}{goodboy@foo.com} % NON VIENE VISUALIZZATA
%\setkomavar{backaddressseparator}{\enspace\textperiodcentered\enspace}
\setkomavar{signature}{(Mario Rossi)}
\setkomavar{place}{Frascati}
\setkomavar{date}{\today}
\setkomavar{enclseparator}{: }

\begin{document}
  \begin{letter}{To: Claire Laterfield}
    \setkomavar{subject}{Greetings}
    \opening{Dear Claire,}
    I am writing this letter because I have nothing better to do.

    \closing{Sincerely,}
  \end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: But then the back address ist not visible through the envelop. Is it possible to remove the top header instead of the backaddress?

Comment: @kerner1000 To remove the header either set class option `firsthead=false` or change the content of  KOMA-Script variable `firsthead`: `\setkomavar{firsthead}{}` or `\setkomavar{firsthead}{<header content>}`.

Comment: thanks esdd, I opened a new question, maybe you can post an example there? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/410157/remove-the-sender-from-letter-header