# Remove the sender from Letter header

Tags: scrlttr2

Per default, the sender info is printed twice, one in the header and also in the address field.

I would like to hide the sender information in the header.

This question is related to [Remove double sender header](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/306873/remove-double-sender-header)

```
 \documentclass[
      fontsize=11pt,
      paper=a4,
      parskip=half,
      enlargefirstpage=on,      %   More space on first page
      fromalign=right,          %   Placement of name in letter head
      fromphone=off,            %   Turn on phone number of sender
      fromrule=aftername,       %   Rule after sender name in letter head
      addrfield=on,             %   Adress field for envelope with window
      backaddress=on,           %   Sender address in this window
      subject=beforeopening,    %   Placement of subject
      locfield=narrow,          %   Additional field for sender
      foldmarks=on,             %   Print foldmarks
      firstfoot=off,            %   Footerbereich
      numericaldate=on,
    ]{scrlttr2}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
    \usepackage{lmodern}


    \setkomafont{fromname}{\sffamily \LARGE}
    \setkomafont{fromaddress}{\sffamily}%% statt \small
    \setkomafont{pagenumber}{\sffamily}
    \setkomafont{subject}{\bfseries}
    \setkomafont{backaddress}{\mdseries}

    \LoadLetterOption{DIN}
    \setkomavar{fromname}{hh}
    \setkomavar{fromaddress}{hh}
    \setkomavar{fromphone}{+39 \,00\,00\,00\,000}
    \setkomavar{fromemail}{goodboy@foo.com} % NON VIENE VISUALIZZATA
    \setkomavar{backaddressseparator}{\enspace\textperiodcentered\enspace}
    \setkomavar{signature}{hh}
    \setkomavar{place}{hh}
    \setkomavar{date}{\today}
    \setkomavar{enclseparator}{: }

    % signature same indention level as rest
    \renewcommand*{\raggedsignature}{\raggedright}

    \setkomavar{location}
        {\raggedleft Kundennummer: hh \\}

    \begin{document}
      \begin{letter}
        {
        hh \\ hh \\ hh \\ 79090 Pfortsheim
        }
        \setkomavar{subject}{hh}
        \opening{Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren,}
        hh
        \closing{Viele Grüße,
        \vspace{1cm}    
        }
      \end{letter}
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set class option `firsthead=false`. Then you can remove options `fromalign`, `fromrule` and `fromphone`:

```
\documentclass[
  fontsize=11pt,
  paper=a4,
  parskip=half,
  enlargefirstpage=on,    % More space on first page
  addrfield=on,           % Adress field for envelope with window
  % following line is changed:
  backaddress=on,         % Sender address in this window
  subject=beforeopening,  % Placement of subject
  locfield=narrow,        % Additional field for sender
  foldmarks=on,           % Print foldmarks
  firsthead=false % <- added
]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\setkomafont{fromname}{\sffamily \LARGE}
\setkomafont{fromaddress}{\sffamily}%% statt \small
\setkomafont{pagenumber}{\sffamily}
\setkomafont{subject}{\bfseries}
%\setkomafont{backaddress}{\mdseries}

%\LoadLetterOption{DIN}
\setkomavar{fromname}{Mario Rossi}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Via Roma 2,\\Frascati}
\setkomavar{fromphone}{+39 \,00\,00\,00\,000}
\setkomavar{fromemail}{goodboy@foo.com} % NON VIENE VISUALIZZATA
%\setkomavar{backaddressseparator}{\enspace\textperiodcentered\enspace}
\setkomavar{signature}{(Mario Rossi)}
\setkomavar{place}{Frascati}
\setkomavar{date}{\today}
\setkomavar{enclseparator}{: }

\begin{document}
  \begin{letter}{To: Claire Laterfield}
    \setkomavar{subject}{Greetings}
    \opening{Dear Claire,}
    I am writing this letter because I have nothing better to do.

    \closing{Sincerely,}
  \end{letter}
\end{document}
```

results in

[image]

Alternatively you can change the variable `firsthead`. If the header should be empty use:

```
\documentclass[
  fontsize=11pt,
  paper=a4,
  parskip=half,
  enlargefirstpage=on,    % More space on first page
  addrfield=on,           % Adress field for envelope with window
  % following line is changed:
  backaddress=on,         % Sender address in this window
  subject=beforeopening,  % Placement of subject
  locfield=narrow,        % Additional field for sender
  foldmarks=on,           % Print foldmarks
]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\setkomafont{fromname}{\sffamily \LARGE}
\setkomafont{fromaddress}{\sffamily}%% statt \small
\setkomafont{pagenumber}{\sffamily}
\setkomafont{subject}{\bfseries}
%\setkomafont{backaddress}{\mdseries}

%\LoadLetterOption{DIN}
\setkomavar{fromname}{Mario Rossi}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Via Roma 2,\\Frascati}
\setkomavar{fromphone}{+39 \,00\,00\,00\,000}
\setkomavar{fromemail}{goodboy@foo.com} % NON VIENE VISUALIZZATA
%\setkomavar{backaddressseparator}{\enspace\textperiodcentered\enspace}
\setkomavar{signature}{(Mario Rossi)}
\setkomavar{place}{Frascati}
\setkomavar{date}{\today}
\setkomavar{enclseparator}{: }

\setkomavar{firsthead}{}% <- added

\begin{document}
  \begin{letter}{To: Claire Laterfield}
    \setkomavar{subject}{Greetings}
    \opening{Dear Claire,}
    I am writing this letter because I have nothing better to do.

    \closing{Sincerely,}
  \end{letter}
\end{document}
```

It is also possible to define your own header:

```
\documentclass[
  fontsize=11pt,
  paper=a4,
  parskip=half,
  enlargefirstpage=on,    % More space on first page
  addrfield=on,           % Adress field for envelope with window
  % following line is changed:
  backaddress=on,         % Sender address in this window
  subject=beforeopening,  % Placement of subject
  locfield=narrow,        % Additional field for sender
  foldmarks=on,           % Print foldmarks
]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\setkomafont{fromname}{\sffamily \LARGE}
\setkomafont{fromaddress}{\sffamily}%% statt \small
\setkomafont{pagenumber}{\sffamily}
\setkomafont{subject}{\bfseries}
%\setkomafont{backaddress}{\mdseries}

%\LoadLetterOption{DIN}
\setkomavar{fromname}{Mario Rossi}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Via Roma 2,\\Frascati}
\setkomavar{fromphone}{+39 \,00\,00\,00\,000}
\setkomavar{fromemail}{goodboy@foo.com} % NON VIENE VISUALIZZATA
%\setkomavar{backaddressseparator}{\enspace\textperiodcentered\enspace}
\setkomavar{signature}{(Mario Rossi)}
\setkomavar{place}{Frascati}
\setkomavar{date}{\today}
\setkomavar{enclseparator}{: }

\setkomavar{firsthead}{<own header>}% <- added

\begin{document}
  \begin{letter}{To: Claire Laterfield}
    \setkomavar{subject}{Greetings}
    \opening{Dear Claire,}
    I am writing this letter because I have nothing better to do.

    \closing{Sincerely,}
  \end{letter}
\end{document}
```